# how to get a time that a requests takes to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, time, response

when we send any ajax request, it takes some time to complete.

Is there any way to get that time in `javascript`?

i have attached a screen shot to elaborate more.
kindly let me know if still unclear. i need the time thatis enclosed in red 
[image]

Comment: Store the `new Date()` when you start, get the `new Date()` when it comes back, subtract the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take note of the time before the request and after the request. The difference will be the time taken to complete the request.

```
var start = new Date().getTime(),
    difference;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: "John",
        location: "Boston"
    }
}).done(function () {
    difference = new Date().getTime() - start;
});
```

Comment: You don't even need `.getTime()`, since the dates will automatically be converted into milliseconds when you subtract them.